# Contagem de numero de acordo com scroll da página jQuery!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal tenho uma PROGRESS BAR que exibe números de 0% até 100%, preciso que quando o scroll for maior que 900px, seja iniciado a contagem dos números por exemplo de 0% a 70% no tempo de 2 segundos.. tenho um código aqui esta funcionando porem.. ele faz a contagem só que se eu mover o scroll da página novamente ele refaz a contagem.. preciso que a animação seja feita só uma unica vez apos o usuário ultrapassar os 900px de scroll.. segue o código:

```
if(scrollTop > 900) {
  $('#front-bar').animate({ width: "70%" }, 2000);
  // Percent count
  $({ counter: 0 }).animate({ counter: 70 }, {
    duration: 2000,
    step : function(){
      $('#front-bar-count').text(Math.ceil(this.counter) + ' %');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar uma variável auxiliar para controlar se já fez a animação e testar a variável antes de animar.

Exemplo:

```
var animacaoFeita = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){ //função de interpretação de evento de scrolling
  ...
  if(scrollTop > 900 && animacaoFeita == false) {
    animacaoFeita = true; //colocar como já feita para não fazer da próxima vez
    $('#front-bar').animate({ width: "70%" }, 2000);
    // Percent count
    $({ counter: 0 }).animate({ counter: 70 }, {
      duration: 2000,
      step : function(){
        $('#front-bar-count').text(Math.ceil(this.counter) + ' %');
      }
    });
  }
  ..
}
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui brother.. vlw!